# ESC/POS: Printing Images + Text in a single row

Tags: printing, alignment, escpos

I'm trying to print a QR code + Text + Image on the same line in an ESC/POS supported thermal printer. I can print them one after the other in new lines, but is it possible to print them in one line? Is this even possible through ESC/POS commands? Here is the example of what I'm trying to do: [image]

Comment: Hi are you find solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using page mode.
The commands that control page mode start, page mode print range, and commands that cannot be used in page mode are described on the following pages.

[ESC L](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=193)

> Select Page mode
> Switches from Standard mode to page mode.

This page shows an example of mixed printing of characters, graphics and barcodes in page mode.
[Print in Page mode](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=271)

Examine the commands used in the examples and how they are used, and apply them.

[ESC W](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=56)

> Set print area in Page mode

[ESC T](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=55)

> Select print direction in Page mode

[GS $](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=59)

> Set absolute vertical print position in Page mode

[GS \](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=63)

> Set relative vertical print position in Page mode

[GS T](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=61)

> Set print position to the beginning of print line

[ESC \](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=57)

> Set relative print position

[FF (in Page mode)](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=12)

> Print and return to Standard mode (in Page mode)