# ESC/POS: how to print QR-code in one line with text

Tags: escpos

Can I paste a QR-code in one line with a text using standard ESC/POS commands, like in the picture? Or I need to render an image with text and QR-code and print this image?

[image]

Comment: It's probably the same question as this one. [ESC/POS: Printing Images + Text in a single row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63501781/9014308)