# Problem formatting single line for printing (ESCPOS)

Tags: escpos, qz-tray

Pretty new to QZTray (2.2.3) and trying to follow the RAW ESCPOS guide (https://qz.io/docs/raw#escp). I'm using an EPSON TM-T82IIIL printer and trying to determine how to do the following all on a single line:

1. Print the ISBN of a book (left justified)
2. Tab stop and print quantity and price per unit
3. Right align and print the total

Per the ESCPOS specs ([https://download4.epson.biz/sec_pubs/pos/reference_en/escpos/esc_la.html](https://stackoverflow.com)), specifically "ESC a" command (alignment), the docs say the following: "*When Standard mode is selected, this command is enabled only when processed at the beginning of the line in Standard mode."*

I'm no guru at receipt printing, but the right alignment isn't working as expected (the final price is in the middle of the receipt line) and presumably it's because of what's written above?

My code snippet is here:

```js
var book_data = [
    'Weir Do' + '\x0A',  // Book Title
    '9781742837581\t' + '1 @ 15.99' + '\x1B' + '\x61' + '\x32' + '15.99', // right align, // ISBN, quantity and price
    '\x0A' + '\x0A' + '\x0A' + '\x0A' + '\x0A' + '\x0A' + '\x0A',
    '\x1B' + '\x69'          // cut paper (old syntax)
];
```

I'm hard-coding things for now just to get it working. Any suggestions - I'm not sure right aligning is possible mid-line like this? Thanks for the help!

Cheers,

Comment: When the online reference falls short, I usually recommend the ESC/POS programming guide (e.g. the PDF), which says this: `ESC a n`: "Aligns all the data in one line to the specified position".  So unfortunately, no, this isn't easily possible to align mid-line.  Solutions that do this are often using manual character padding  to simulate this (which is unfortunate because it's so common for receipts it would be nice if the firmware could handle mid-line alignment).

Comment: If you continue reading, you'll also see `ESC a n`: "This command has no effect in page mode.".

Comment: It may be easier to get advice and answers if you have an image of the desired print result, the actual print result, and a hexadecimal representation of the data sent to the printer.

Comment: @kunif for someone familiar with ESC/POS, I believe the question to be precise and clear (alignment need not be visualized to be understood).  The programming guide has this issue documented clearly.  There may be pagemode solutions which can workaround this (albeit without alignment, so not directly answering the question), which is why the "answer in the comments" is here for the OP.  This behavior is a limitation of the ESC/POS language.  ESC/POS uses fixed width; as a result, most developers use manual padding for midline alignment.  In context of QZ Tray, the `data` is padded before sent.

Comment: @kunif with regards to the request for "a hexadecimal representation", most of the OPs example is already in hexadecimal format, denoted by the JavaScript `\x` hexadecimal escape sequence.

Comment: Are you observing the actual data sent to the device, such as a serial port/printer port, rather than the representation in the program source code? It would be best to check to determine whether the problem is with the software you are using (in this case, QZ Tray?) or with the coding itself. If you're using software for the first time, don't you need to check it from various angles? Or have you tried printing with other model printers using the same program/data?

Comment: In addition, it may be a good idea to create sample data using the tools [Send Data Tool](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=5027&scat=47&pcat=52) and usage examples [Issuing Receipts with Barcodes](https://download4.epson.biz/sec_pubs/pos/reference_en/escpos/receipt_with_barcode.html) provided by EPSON as a reference, and compare it with the results processed by QZ Tray (data to be sent and print results).

Comment: Getting back to the basics of your question, you need to use page mode. Have you written ESC/POS commands for their mode settings and printing? Please refer to these articles and add an image of what you want to do to your question. [ESC/POS: Printing Images + Text in a single row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63501781/9014308), [ESC/POS: how to print QR-code in one line with text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77569664/9014308), [Print in Page mode](https://download4.epson.biz/sec_pubs/pos/reference_en/escpos/pagemode.html)